# OVH: Cron not detected by CiviCRM

Tags: cron, civicrm-home, hosting

I'm working on a drupal website with a CiviCRM platform which is hosted by OVH. My cron seems to be working, [image]

but CiviCRM is not detecting it. Is that normal ?

Thanks in advance for your advices.

Comment: I'm also trying to configure cron to run on a shared server hosted by OVH.. So unable to run any command :-( I also need to encapsulate a php script and call over HTTP; did you manage to configure and have it up and running?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I recommend following the documentation to configure your cron entry.

- https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/setup/jobs/#commands

This page documents method for using built-in CLI commands (`cli.php`) and externally packaged CLI tools (`drush` or `cv`).

The method shown in your screenshot does not appear to match those docs:

- The task is initiated from within the `bin` directory rather than CiviCRM website root (this might or might not be a factor)
- The task uses `cron.php` using CLI SAPI, not the CLI tools documented. ([`cron.php`](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/master/bin/cron.php) uses `$_REQUEST` for its inputs)
- The task does not specify a CiviCRM scheduled job (eg `Job.execute`)

Following the docs is probably the best next step. If that doesn't work, update your question to include the amended command and output as a text for further guidance.

`cron.php` is documented as intended to be called over HTTP in that page, which you can also do using other CLI tools like `curl`.

Comment: Hello Chris,

Thanks for your answer. I tried to follow the doc as you recommended.

Here is what I did. As OVH doesn't provide command line access to the server, I followed the "HTTP method" paragraph by creating a script like this :  https://imgur.com/iKpx4tc, then executed it on the OVH interface : https://imgur.com/mDjnNK0. Like yesterday, OVH executed without errors : https://imgur.com/zo1q4jh, but CiviCRM is still not detecting the cron activity.